# How to get the name of the Parent Table with the help of Column name in Sys.Columns

Tags: sql-server

I wanted to get the table name. I have the column name and when I try to look up at the Sys.Columns table I get the matching name of the column. How will I get the table name to which the required column is associated

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) AS TableSchemaName,
       OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS TableName
FROM sys.columns
WHERE name = 'YourColumnName'
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps:

```
select t.name from sys.columns c
inner join sys.tables t
on c.object_id = t.object_id
where c.name = 'insert column name here'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
declare @columnName As varchar(50) = 'ParentColumnName'

select t.name from sys.tables t 
join sys.columns c 
   on c.object_id = t.object_id
and c.name = @columnName
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select OBJECT_NAME(object_id) as TableName from sys.Columns where name='columnNamehere'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name as 'TableName' from sys.tables where object_id=
(select object_id from sys.columns where name='UserName')
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question, but the answers listed to date do not get at what the parent table name is for a view's columns, nor if a column is aliased to have a new name with respect to the column name in the parent table.

Unfortunately, (at least in 2008R2) it seems that even with registering your Views to a Schema, the `referencing_minor_id` of `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities` (or the equivalent column from `sys.SQL_Modules`) is always set to zero.  However, you can retrieve all referred-to tables (and parent views), along with which fields of those tables are queried with `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities` (or `sys.SQL_Modules`).  However, it does not capture the oorder of those bindings, so the following won't quite work to link view columns directly to table columns, but it'll provide an approximation:

```
DECLARE @obj_name nvarchar(50) = 'Table_or_View_name_here';
with obj_id as (
    select object_id, name, OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id)+'.'+name as qualified_name from sys.all_objects as o
    where o.name = @obj_name 
),
tv_columns as ( -- table or view
    select o.name as Obj_Name, c.* from sys.columns as c join 
        obj_id as o on
            c.object_id=o.object_id
),
sql_referenced_entities as  (
    SELECT
        o.name as referencing_name,
        o.object_id,
        COALESCE(NULLIF(referencing_minor_id,0),ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (select 'NO_SORT'))) as referencing_minor_id,
        referenced_server_name,
        referenced_database_name,
        referenced_schema_name,
        referenced_entity_name,
        referenced_minor_name,
        referenced_id,
        referenced_minor_id,
        referenced_class,
        referenced_class_desc,
        is_caller_dependent,
        is_ambiguous
    FROM obj_id as o, sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities((select qualified_name from obj_id), 'OBJECT') where referenced_minor_id<>0
)  
    select 
        c.object_id as object_id,
        o.name as object_name,
        c.column_id,
        c.name as column_name,
        c2.object_id as parent_table_object_id,
        o2.name as parent_table_name, 
        c2.column_id as parent_column_id,
        c2.name as parent_column_name
--      ,c.*,
--      ,c2.* 
    from sys.columns as c join 
        obj_id as o on
            c.object_id=o.object_id left outer join
        (sql_referenced_entities as s join
            sys.all_objects as o2 on
                s.referenced_id=o2.object_id and s.referenced_class=1 join
            sys.columns as c2 on
                s.referenced_id=c2.object_id and s.referenced_minor_id=c2.column_id
        ) on 
            c.object_id=s.object_id and c.column_id=s.referencing_minor_id
```

To get the true aliases used, as well as any calculations involving the combinations of multiple fields, you would have to parse the output of either `OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID('schema.view'))` (or potentially `exec sp_helptext 'schema.view'`), as follows

Starting with `OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID('schema.view'))`

1. Mark what is enclosed in single quotes as superseeding the removal and other rules to follow
2. Remove blocks between `/* */` comments
3. Remove any text after `--`, up to the next linebreak sequence (see `EXEC SP_HELPTEXT 'sp_helptext'` for their end-of-line code)
4. Look up table/subselect aliases from the `FROM` clause
5. Parse out the SELECT clause and break on commas, rather than end-of-line.
6. Reduce any contiguous whitespace to a single space character. Force whitespace before `[` and after `]` when a dot/period (or whitespace) don't already appear.
7. We'll put the above into a stored procedure that we'll call `usp_helptext_for_view`
8. See which `table_alias.field_name` are aliased or simply appear as `field_name`. See the below code snippet to see how to seperate the field alias from the definition.
9. Link the view to the table as appropriate.

`drop table #s
    create table #s (id bigint identity(1,1) primary key, text nvarchar(max))
    insert into #s (text) exec usp_helptext_for_view @qualified_viewname
    with s as (select
      id,
      text,
      az=(select
            MIN(x*(case x when 0 then null else 1 end)) FROM (VALUES 
                 (charindex(@viewfieldname,text COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS)),
                 (charindex('['+@viewfieldname+']',text COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS)),
                 (charindex('AS ['+@viewfieldname+']',text COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS)), 
                 (charindex('as '+@viewfieldname,text COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS))
           ) AS value(x)
          ),
      NULLIF(charindex('=',text),0)) as eq --oh, the irony of how the two different styles are applied
    FROM #s
    )
    SELECT
      @viewfieldname as ViewField,
      CASE eq WHEN NULL
        THEN IIF(az IS NULL, NULL, LEFT(text, az-2))
        ELSE RIGHT(text,LENGTH(text)-eq) -- alternately ELSE CASE az WHEN NULL THEN NULL WHEN &lt;eq THEN RIGHT(text,LENGTH(text)-eq) ELSE NULL END
      END as ViewFieldDefinition,
      id as sortPosition
    FROM s
    WHERE text like '%'+@viewfieldname+'%' -- you should be able to eliminate this clause without affecting the results.
    ORDER BY id, @viewfieldname`